# SSIS Derived column based on input columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I realize this may be a fundamental question but I'm struggling to understand the syntax behind expressions in derived columns. I have a simple case:

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET [DerivedColumn] = 1
WHERE NOT([InputColumn] IN ('Approved','Verbally Approved'))
```

This is my SQL and I'd like to know how this translates in an SSIS derived column or some other method that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) to translate this expression, but you should specify the output value if this condition is not met, as an example:

```
[InputColumn] != "Approved" && [InputColumn] != "Verbally Approved" ? 1 : 0
```